# Add centos repository to Amazon Linux instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, foreman

I'm trying to add the following yum repository to my AWS instance:

https://centos.pkgs.org/7/centos-x86_64/

The issue is that there is no repodata/ directory with the required metadata in this source, how can I add this repository without getting the following error:

```
yum-config-manager --add-repo https://centos.pkgs.org/7/centos-x86_64/
yum install -y katello
https://centos.pkgs.org/7/centos-x86_64/repodata/repomd.xml: [Errno 12] Timeout on 
https://centos.pkgs.org/7/centos-x86_64/repodata/repomd.xml: (28, 'Connection timed out 
after 5001 milliseconds')
```

I'm currently missing multiple dependencies like python-rhsm and selinux-policy which both only exist on the centos.pkgs repository.

Answer (score 4):

Your URL is wrong, the following worked for me:

```
RUN curl http://mirror.centos.org/centos/7/os/x86_64/RPM-GPG-KEY-CentOS-7 -o RPM-GPG-KEY-CentOS-7
RUN rpm --import RPM-GPG-KEY-CentOS-7
RUN yum-config-manager --add-repo='http://mirror.centos.org/centos/7/os/x86_64/'
```

Note that a lot of their packages will conflict with Amazon's pre-installed packages.

One workaround I've found is to **not** add that repo, and instead use `yum install <direct_rpm_link>` for all of my installations. I had to manually resolve some dependencies myself by adding more .rpm links, but at least it worked in the end.